# Can't apply justify content center on screen resize

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve this:
The div's content should be in the center at every screen size. But when I resize the browser content of the div spans out of the whilst the parent div remains in the center.

I tried to limit the width to a particular size, but the content becomes joined together.
I also tried giving the parent div `flex-wrap: wrap;` but it does not break little by little, it just becomes block, I mean on to of each other.
This is my code:

```html
    <div class="optionsPar d-flex">
                            <div class="options  mx-auto">
                                <div class="row" style="width: inherit;">
                                    <div class="d-flex">
                                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 d-flex align-items-center                                                       mt-4">
                                            <strong>.com</strong><span>$11.25</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 d-flex align-items-center mt-4">
                                            <strong>.com</strong><span>$11.25</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 d-flex align-items-center mt-4">
                                            <strong>.com</strong><span>$11.25</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 d-flex align-items-center mt-4">
                                            <strong>.com</strong><span>$11.25</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 d-flex align-items-center mt-4">
                                            <strong>.com</strong><span>$11.25</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 d-flex align-items-center mt-4">
                                            <strong>.com</strong><span>$11.25</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Please I need help, thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you are using bootstrap. Please check how to properly use bootstrap rows and columns. `col-` classes should be direct descendants of `row`. No need to use a `d-flex` since `row` has that automatically. Also no need to write `width: inherit` to the `row` class, define the width by setting the width on the outer div. Like using a `.container` or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

### **You Must use Box-sizing-border box to your main div of class optionPra**

`<style> .optionsPar{box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%;} </style>`